# How to group a list by a specific value in Freemarker?

Tags: java, html, grouping, netsuite, freemarker

I need to group the list based on the value 'item' in the specific list. So each group might have a separate list for each. Please, anyone suggest as I m new in free marker.

```
*My Code:*

  <#list searchdata.value as detail>
    <tr>
      <td>${detail_index+1}</td>
      <td>${detail.season}</td>
      <td>${detail.location}</td>
      <td>${detail.gender}</td>
      <td>${detail.item}</td> <!-- group by this-->
      <td>${detail.style}</td>
      <td>${detail.wash}</td>
    </tr>
  </#list>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Actually, it's not that painful to implement in the template language. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588885/606679

You can't do that in FreeMarker (OK, not in a sane way). You need to receive the data already grouped. Or, you need an utility class written in Java, that you call from FreeMarker.