Is there an efficient way to group same item and sum qty and amount?
<#if record.item?has_content>

<table class="itemtable" style="margin-top:10px;width:100%;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th align="left" colspan="9">Product Description</th>
    <th align="center" colspan="4">Packaging Type</th>
    <th align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity@label} /<br />Weight (T)</th>
    <th align="center" colspan="3">${item.rate@label} (${record.currency})</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount@label} (${record.currency})</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</#if><tr>
    <td colspan="9" line-height="150%"><span class="itemname"><!--${item.item}--></span>${item.description}</td>
    <td align="center" colspan="4">${item.custcol_mss_bag_type}</td>
    <td align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td align="center" colspan="3">${item.rate?string['#,##0.00']}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount?string['#,##0.00']}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list><!-- end items --></table>

<hr />

This is custom record that pulls line data from different Sales Order.
My issue is many time there are same item that appears on many lines making the printout heavy and repetitive.
I saw this extract online
<#assign item_group = {}/>

<#List record item as item>
    <#assign item_key = item.item/>
    <#assign item_group = item_group + {item.item: item}>
</#list>

<#list item_group?values as item>
    <td align="center" colspan="4">${item.item}</td>
    <td align="center" colspan="4">${item.description}</td>
</#list>

But I don't see how to use it or if it applies to my scenario.
Please note that I'm not very accustomed to NetSuite Advanced HTML nor am I a developer.
Is there a way to make grouping?

Yes. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013395/does-oracle-netsuite-advanced-pdf-template-have-group-by-and-sum-functions/44030039#44030039

This question is similar to: Does Oracle NetSuite Advanced PDF Template have "Group by" and "SUM" Functions?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This might help you: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58913777/26431772
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588885/26431772
